# Ошибка: Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@telephoneNumber"

Tags: c#, sql-server

Подскажите, делаю так, но выходит ошибка: Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@telephoneNumber", хотя параметры занес правильно.

```
foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
            {

                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BookPhones(Name, telephoneNumber, Mail) VALUES (@Name, @telephoneNumber, @Mail)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString());

                if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephoneNumber", result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString());
                }

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

Comment: У вас параметр @telephoneNumber добавляется по условию, очевидно оно не выполняется. И откажитесь от использования функции `AddWithValue`, которая являет собой [зло в чистом виде](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Denis Rubashkin, скажи, что тогда лучше использовать?

Comment: В статье ведь описано в чем проблема и пример приведен, например, если тип поля BookPhones.Name `VARCHAR(30)`: `command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы условие отрабатывалось и заносилось в БД?

Comment: Уберите `if`, если при отсутствии номера нужно добавлять запись с telephoneNumber = NULL или перенесите его в начало цикла, если записи с пустым номером не нужно добавлять в базу

Comment: Да, номера отсутствуют. И если нет номера, то NULL. А как это без условия записать, нам ведь нужно все равно проверить есть номер или нет.